# what's the point behind converting a List to an Set and than back to a List in python?

Tags: python, list, casting, set

i just found this code in a project i'm working on:

```
applicant_function = []
for ...:
    applicant_function.append(...)
...
applicant_function = list(set(applicant_function))
```

does anyone have an idea what's the meaning behind this?

Comment: As the answers point out, converting a `list` to a `set` is a common way to remove duplicates.  In this particular example there's no point in having the first `list`: just create a `set` and add each item to it.  And the second `list` is only required if the code that uses the collection _requires_ it to be a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set does not allow duplicates. The purpose is presumably to obtain a list without duplicates (every element appears at most once in the list).

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is this:-

```
applicant_function = []   #initializing an empty list
for ...:         #for loop initialization
    applicant_function.append(...)     #appending elements to list
...
applicant_function = list(set(applicant_function))    #converting applicant_function to a set to remove duplicate elements.
```